# return RedirectToAction vs return Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my web application there is an action called, that, depending on a value, either returns another action or executes the current action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(int id)
{
    bool someValue = AnyClass.GetSomeValue(); // doesn't matter what value: it's a boolean

    if (someValue)
    {
        // should I:
        return RedirectToAction("MyOtherAction", new {id = id});
        // or should I:
        return await MyOtherAction(id);
    }
    // do something here
    return View();
}

public async Task<ActionResult> MyOtherAction(int id)
{
    // do something else here
    return View();
}
```

so should I work in the first action with

`RedirectToAction("MyOtherAction", new {id = id});`

or better with

`return await MyOtherAction(id);`

to switch to the other action? In the end, wouldn't they both do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the two is what the user will end up seeing in the address bar of their browser.

With `return RedirectToAction("MyOtherAction", new {id = id});` you are generating an HTTP redirect meaning that if the other action has the route `/my-other-action` the user will end up seeing that in their address bar and it will be a new entry in their browser's history.

If on the other hand you do `return await MyOtherAction(id);` then the result of `MyOtherAction` will be rendered as the result of the current URL the user is visiting (e.g. `/my-action`).

Either of these approaches is valid and so it is up to you to determine which of these experiences you want the user of your site to have.